# Python Flask-RestFul with MySQL db - multiple requests at the same time returns MYSQL SSL error

Tags: python, mysql

I am not exactly sure what is going on, but here is the scenario.

I have a flask-restful api that is returning data it pulls from a mySQL db.

I have two angular components that show at the same time, and make this request simultaneously.

```
this.http.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/MovingDayAverage/" + ticker + "&" + days);
```

In the python back-end, I use mysql-connector-python and the following select statement

```
sql = "SELECT Close, Date FROM stockdata WHERE Ticker='%s' AND Date > '%s' ORDER BY Date Desc" % (ticker, date_8_years_ago)
```

If I make the request with the same ticker and days value, I get no problem. If I make the requests one at a time with different ticker values, and ensure the second request only runs after the first is complete, I get no problem.

If I make the requests at the same time with two different ticker values, I get this error in python.

```
2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'localhost:3306', system error: 1 [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:2607)
```

Any ideas why this might be happening? I have not implemented any sort of SSL. This is all being done locally.